# hashCode da assinatura do APK

Tags: java, android, mobile

Eu preciso retorna um hashCode único da assinatura do apk.

```
Signature[] sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
for (Signature sig : sigs)
{
    Trace.i("MyApp", "Signature hashcode : " + sig.hashCode());
}
```

Eu concluir que esse código retorna o hashCode da assinatura da .jks, então todos apk que usar a mesma .jks vai retornar o mesmo hashCode, mas eu precisava do hashCode único da apk.

**Alguém sabe se é possível trazer o hashCode da assinatura do apk que seja unica?**